# hal_delay in external interrupt problem

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, embedded, interrupts

I wrote a simple C program for STM32:

*main.c*

```
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      HAL_Delay(400);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_Delay(400);
  }
```

*it.c*

```
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_Delay(1000);

  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
}
```

There is no problem when there is no delay interrupt; it enters ISR and exits.

But when delay interrupts,
the program gets stuck at delay ().

My RCC settings are correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like `EXTI0_IRQHandler()` is preventing the systick timer from running. I believe `HAL_Delay()` uses the systick timer. So the timer stops incrementing and the `HAL_Delay()` function waits forever.

It may be possible to fix this by adjusting the priority of `EXTI0_IRQHandler()` lower than the systick mechanism so that systick continues to run even while `EXTI0_IRQHandler()` is running. Or you could re-write it so that `EXTI0_IRQHandler()` sets a global flag, and then read the flag in the main loop. If the flag is set, you toggle D14 in the main loop then clear the flag and call `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0)` from the main loop.

Comment: Yes, by default, `HAL_Delay()` depends on the `SysTick` timer. In most cases when programming STM32 MCUs, the SysTick must have the highest priority in order to avoid deadlocks due to interrupt handlers using `HAL_Delay()` (which is a bad pattern anyway, but it happens, not only in the code in the question).

Answer (score 4):

When studying embedded systems on the beginner level, we are always told to never write long ISRs. Especially don't call delays or print functions from inside the ISR.

Though in this case the most convenient fix might be a quick & dirty release of the global interrupt mask. Something like this:

```
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  __asm("CPSIE i"); // depending on your compiler's inline asm syntax

  ...
}
```

This allows other interrupts to occur even though you are still inside your ISR. Essentially you yield up your ISR's exclusive access to the CPU.